# Array multidimensional javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

this is my first post and i hope the comunity can help me.
I want to create an array in javascript, i tried but i can't.
this is the array in php, how i do this in javascript?

```
$structure = array(
            0 => array(
                'columns' => array(
                    array('tipo' => 'banner', 'data' => array('name' => '61b9f0845b7da.jpg'))
                )
            ),
            1 => array(
                'columns' => array(
                    array('tipo' => 'product', 'data' => array('id_product' => 1233198)), 
                    array('tipo' => 'product', 'data' => array('id_product' => 2021097, 'color' => '333'))
                )
            )`enter code here`
        );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want an array of objects.

```js
[
    {
        columns: [{
            tipo: 'banner',
            data: {
                name: '61b9f0845b7da.jpg'
            }
        }]
    }, 
    {
        columns: [{
            tipo: 'product',
            data: {
                id_product: 1233198
            }
        }, {
            tipo: 'product',
            data: {
                id_product: 2021097,
                color: '333'
            }
        }]
    }
]
```

Comment: Yes, i woke up this morning and i did, yesterday my head was not working, a hard day. thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Luis Happy to help.